# Is there an easy way to strip HTML from a QString in Qt?

Tags: html, qt, strip

I have a QString with some HTML in it... is there an easy way to strip the HTML from it? I basically want just the actual text content.

```
<i>Test:</i><img src="blah.png" /><br> A test case
```

Would become:

```
Test: A test case
```

I'm curious to know if Qt has a string function or utility for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may try to iterate through the string using QXmlStreamReader class and extract all text (if you HTML string is guarantied to be well formed XML).

Something like this:

```
QXmlStreamReader xml(htmlString);
QString textString;
while (!xml.atEnd()) {
    if ( xml.readNext() == QXmlStreamReader::Characters ) {
        textString += xml.text();
    }
}
```

but I'm unsure that its 100% valid ussage of QXmlStreamReader API since I've used it quite longe time ago and may forget something.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not trying to validate it or extract it. I just want rid of it.

Comment: Oh, and the text I'm getting *is* from a trusted source (not user input) so I should be fine.

Comment: Is not working for case when no any html tags. So textString will be empty string.

Answer (score 38):

```
QString s = "<i>Test:</i><img src=\"blah.png\" /><br> A test case";
s.remove(QRegExp("<[^>]*>"));
// s == "Test: A test case"
```

Comment: This answer won't suffice for strings with HTML entities e.g. &lt;

Comment: The problem with this, off the top of my head, is that `<br>` gets removed rather than get converted to the newline character.

Comment: @Marcus So exactly what the question asked for. None of the HTML gets converted to anything, that's a totally different request

Answer (score 32):

If you don't care about performance that much then `QTextDocument` does a pretty good job of converting HTML to plain text.

```
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setHtml( htmlString );

return doc.toPlainText();
```

I know this question is old, but I was looking for a quick and dirty way to handle incorrect HTML. The XML parser wasn't giving good results.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. It keeps basic format like breaks.

Comment: Perhaps a slightly better solution would be to use `QTextDocumentFragment`:
`QString plainText = QTextDocumentFragment::fromHtml( htmlString ).toPlainText();`

Comment: You should make this is a real answer, rather than a comment. Best solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

the situation that some html is not quite validate xml make it worse to work it out correctly.

If it's valid xml (or not too bad formated), I think QXmlStreamReader + QXmlStreamEntityResolver might not be bad idea.

Sample code in: https://github.com/ycheng/misccode/blob/master/qt_html_parse/utils.cpp

(this can be a comment, but I still don't have permission to do so)

Answer (score -5):

this answer is for who read this post later and using Qt5 or later. simply escape the html characters using inbuilt functions as below.

```
QString str="<h1>some hedding </h1>"; // a string containing html tags.
QString esc=str.toHtmlEscaped(); //esc contains the html escaped srring.
```

Comment: I'm not looking to escape the tags, I wish to remove them.

Comment: `QString::toHtmlEscaped` does not remove html tags. Just converts characters like `<`, `>` etc, to html codes.