# Get plain text from QString with HTML tags

Tags: html, qt, qstring

I have QString with html tags. Why can i get plain text from this string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to strip HTML from a QString in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799379/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strip-html-from-a-qstring-in-qt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to strip off the HTML tags from the string. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799379/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strip-html-from-a-qstring-in-qt) for instance.

Answer (score 9):

str.remove(QRegExp("<[^>]*>"));

Comment: This is not a Qt way, but this is a nice way in some situation. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure it is the shortest way.

Comment: @k06a Will that *always* work? What about concerns in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @neuronet real world websites html contain a lot of errors and inconsistencies. So parsing html is not a good idea IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit dusty now, but for anyone checking, it is (has become?) possible to use `QTextDocumentFragment` to convert HTML to plaintext in the Qt way.

This approach may offer consistency dependending on your purpose, as well as robustness (of course depending on the Qt folks time :) - but their user base is sizable, and so far it has worked perfectly for me).

I tried something like the below out in Python, I think the mechanics should be about the same in C++ too.

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QTextDocumentFragment

plain = QTextDocumentFragment.fromHtml(
    "<body>someHtml<br/><b>it was so booold!</b></body>"
).toPlainText()
```

(Additionally, the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocumentfragment.html#fromHtml) suggests that you can just pass in the `QString` to `fromHtml` there.)