# Get Plain text from a QLabel with Rich text

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qlabel

I have a `QLabel` that contains rich text.
I want to extract just the actual (visible) 'text' from the `QLabel`, and none of the code for formatting.
I essentially need a function similiar to the `'.toPlainText'` method of other `Qt Widgets`.

I can not simply call `.text()` and string manipulate away the html tags as suggested in this thread [Get plain text from QString with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999967/get-plain-text-from-qstring-with-html-tags), since the returned `QString` contains all the `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">` nonsense.

How do I extract the plain text?

(I'm open to any method, even if indirect. eg; Pre-existing functions that convert html to plain text)

Thanks!

Specs:
python 2.7.2
PyQt4
Windows 7

Comment: I've not tried it myself, but it looks like `QTextCodec` is what you need (documentation at http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html).

Comment: RTF doesn't seem to be a supported encoding (unless I'm missing something). Never mind, I've found a messy work-around

Comment: Can't you just treat Qt Rich Text as html? The Qt document here (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-text.html) says: "Rich text is defined using HTML-style markup."

Comment: Yea! (Is html supported by QTextCodec? I'm just going to assume so, since it's only logical if supported by the GUI framework. I'm not very knowledgeable in this whole 'mark-up',text format business! Sorry.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a [`QTextDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html) to do the conversion:

```
doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
doc.setHtml(label.text())
text = doc.toPlainText()
```

Comment: Oh yeah, bit more direct than my method. Embarrassed I missed that :|

Answer (score 2):

Here's a messy work around (for python - PyQt)

```
def Extract_PlainText(label):
    Rtf_text = label.text()
    Temp_Obj = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    Temp_Obj.setText(Rtf_text)
    Plain_text = Temp_Obj.toPlainText()
    del Temp_Obj
    return Plain_text
```

Inspired by http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/707370-convert-rtf-plain-text

Comment: Ofcourse the 'del Temp_Obj' is completely unnescessary, but I find it quaint